# I had just pressed ctrl z in sculpting mode and this happen.. can any one help me out

Tags: sculpting, sculpt

[image]
I had just pressed ctrl z in sculpting mode and this happen.. can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 1):

try Ctrl + shift + Z to cancel the Ctrl Z

Answer (score 0):

For some reason a bunch of face sets get created when you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Z</kbd> every once in a while.

You can clear this by going to the top bar

1. Click *Face Sets*
2. Select *Face Set From Visible*

Note: I think if you have pre-existing face sets, they will be removed by this workflow, but if you're just sculpting with one face set it's a quick fix.